# Mover vistas creadas dinamicamente

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Estoy haciendo una aplicación simple en la que se añaden diferentes vistas dinámicamente (botones,sliders,etiquetas,etc) a una **view** que hace de contenedor.

Esto ya funciona ,pero el siguiente paso seria poder mover (drag) estas vistas creadas para colocarlas en la posición deseada en la pantalla.

Para ello he puesto un botón en el `navigation bar` con doble funcionalidad, `Edit` y `Run`. No se como conseguir que en el modo `run` ,las vistas respondan normalmente (si es un botón ,poder hacer `tap`,si es un `slider` ,poder cambiar su posición..) pero en el modo `edit` solo respondan al `Pan Gesture` para poder arrastrarlas, y aunque se hiciera un `touch` ,no respondieran a sus eventos habituales ,solo al Pan ,mientras el botón este en `Edit`.

Había pensado poner un panel (`UIView`) que pasara a la primera `posicion(.bringToFront())` ,pero las vistas que hay debajo siguen respondiendo al `touch`. Si pongo `.userInteraction()` del panel en false, las views no responden pero el panel tampoco

[image: Pantalla par elegir view]

[image: Pantalla donde se añaden las vistas elegidas dinámicamente]

Comment: El botón de Edit/Run es por funcionalidad de lo que quieres hacer? o es para saber cuando tienes que moverlo o cuando tienes que hacer el Action? Por lo que entiendo, lo que quieres hacer es que en un moneto determinado poner el dedo encima de un ítem y moverlo de sitio, pero cuando haga un tap que se ejecute el IBAction?

Comment: El boton edit/run diferencia dos modos de funcionamiento ,cuando se pulsa edit ,las vistas solo deberian responder al evento pan gesture para poder posicionarlas , habilita el boton + para poder añadir mas vistas y cambia el titulo por el de run.Cuando se pulsa run ,las vistas funcionan normalmente y no tienen que responder al pan gesture(el boton recibe tap,el slider se puede cambiar de posicion,el switch puede activarse/desactivarse,etc) ,el titulo se cambia a edit y se desabilita el boton + de añadir mas vistas.

Comment: Porque no cambia el gesto de cada elemento según esta en run o en edit?

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que estoy preguntando,como hacerlo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno al final hice una pequeña chapuza que a falta de algo mejor parece que funciona.Primero una view transparente del mismo tamaño que la view contenedora:

```
let frame = container.frame
let panel = UIView(frame: frame);panel.tag = -1000
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer (target: self, action:#selector(pan(sender:)))
panel.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
view.addSubview(panel)
```

Luego recorro todas las vistas para ver si alguna contiene el mismo punto que el capturado en panel transparente al inicio del panGesture ( .began )

```
@IBAction func pan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
switch sender.state {
case .began :
  let p: CGPoint = sender.location(in: view.viewWithTag(-1000))
  for v in container.subviews {
    if v.frame.contains(p){
      selected = v
      difference.x = p.x - selected!.center.x
      difference.y = p.y - selected!.center.y
    }
  }
case .changed :
  let location = sender.location(in: view.viewWithTag(-1000))
  selected?.center.x = location.x - (difference.x)
  selected?.center.y = location.y - (difference.y)
case .ended :
  selected = nil
default:
  print("Gesture indefinido")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer este tipo de 'drags' se puede utilizar el **UICollectionView** que permite mover celdas y a parte interactuar con ellas , luego a través de boleanos ya indicarias cuando se pueden mover y cuando no.

Si no , tal como comentas el problema es que mientras editas el switch por ejemplo sigue funcionando igual , para esto quizás podrías probar de hacer que mientras estes en el modo edición los objetos que haya no sean interactuables , con un **switch.enabled** o algo de esto.

Comment: por lo que he visto las CollectionView son como una especie de tablas pero para vistas,con esto no creo que pueda conseguir la libertad de mover cada vista a cualquier parte de la view contenedora.

Comment: Por otro lado,poniendo a false el enable ,tampoco recibiria el pan gesture ,ademas que las vistas quedan semiborradas cuando el enable esta en false y no queda bien ,da la sensacion que no se puede interactuar...lo ideal seria poder poner un panel encima que captara el tap y poder averiguar que vista se encuentra debajo ,cogiendo su referencia,luego el pan gesture se haria tambien en este mismo panel y la vista se moveria a las mismas coordenadas del pan gesture....

Comment: El collection view podria ser esa view contenedora , para que te hagas una idea la pantalla principal del iphone es un collection view y el mover los iconos y eliminarlos lo provoca el uiCollecton view.
Si bien es cierto que no quieres utilizar eso y el gesto del enabled no te gusta , hay una propiedad llamada 'userInteraction' o algo asi que anula cualquier interacción con el objeto sin hacer el gesto transparente del Enabled.
Desde mi punto de vista hay que evitar utilizar UIViews para hacer ñapas de gestos y capas transparentes por encima etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Perdón, pero no he tenido tiempo antes. Creo que quieres poder mover los elementos donde quieras dentro de la pantalla y que ademas funcionen cuando haces tap. Tengo algo que hice una vez pero esta en ObjC, espero que esto sea lo que quieres y que te sirva. Básicamente tienes que añadir el gesto pan a la vista para poder mover lo que haya en ella. Debes tener acceso a los items que hay en la vista, Yo utilice un singleton para ir guardando, ya que podia tener 2 ó 30, también podrias recorrer los items de la vista

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hacenPan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Ahora tienes que hacer el acción del pan. Para esto deberas ir reconociendo los estados y guardar el item que estas moviendo

```
-(void)hacenPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan{
static Figura *f;
//compruebo los estados del pan para saber si esta comenzando o terminando...
if ( pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    //se esta moviendo
    CGPoint currentPosition = [pan locationInView:self.view];
    if ( f ) {
        CGRect fr=f.shape.frame;
        fr.origin.x=currentPosition.x;
        fr.origin.y=currentPosition.y;
        f.shape.frame=fr;
    }

} else if ( pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //comienza el pan, busco la figura que hay debajo
    CGPoint inicio =[pan locationInView:self.view];
    //comprobar si el punto pertenece a alguna vista existente
    f=[ArraySingleton buscaFiguraConElPunto:inicio];
} else if ( pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //termino el pan, elimino la fogura que tuviera guardada
    f=nil;
}
```

}

Esto lo que hace es cuando empieza a reconocer el pan, busca donde ha comenzado y si hay una Figura en esas coordenadas. Deberas ir guardando en algún sitio donde esta cada figura. Yo lo tengo en un singleton porque lo decidí así, pero puedes ser una array en el controlador o como quieras y a partir de ahi he de quedarme con la Figura que quieras mover, ya que este evento se va a llamar muchas veces, así que cuando muevas el dedo ira por  UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged y es ahi donde mueves el item a la nueva posición del dedo, con esto podrás arrastrar los items por la pantalla y se quedaran donde levantes el dedo.
Yo en mi caso siempre usaba el mismo tipo, que es Figura.

Espero que sea lo que buscabas y que te sirva